# My Tomcat rewrite rule not working and I don't know why

Tags: tomcat, url-rewriting, rules

I cannot troubleshoot the rewrite rule, please help to find the missing peace.

The regex seems to be fine, as I tested replacement in Notepad++.

Source URL is:
    http://qf.myserver.com:8080/archive?get&pVersion=0045&contRep=T1&docId=F40343A990B01ED8BAF97A695626C259&ixUser=QFNCOTAAP001&ixAppl=libdsh&accessMode=r&authId=QFNCOTAAP001&expiration=20181219153855&secKey=MIIBXAYJKoZIhvcNAQcCo

Target URL is:
     http://qf.myserver.com:8080/archive?get&pVersion=0045&contRep=T1&docId=F40343A990B01ED8BAF97A695626C259&ixUser=QFNCOTAAP001&ixAppl=libdsh&accessMode=r&authId=QFNCOTAAP001

The RewriteCond should check for links which contain 'archive?get' and '&contRep=T1' and the remove everything from the URL backwards including and after &expiration...

```
context.xml
<Context>
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve" />
</Context>

in \WEB-INF\rewrite.config and \conf\Catalina\localhost\rewrite.config:

RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_URI}      (archive\?get.*)(\&contRep=T1.*)
RewriteRule     ^(.*).expiration.*      $1
```

It does not replace the URL, Tomcat still executes the source URL.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was in the RewriteCond, as what I wanted to filter was not available in %{REQUEST_URI}. Now I have

```
RewriteCond     %{QUERY_STRING} ^(get.*&contRep=T1&.*)&expiration.*$
RewriteRule     ^(.*)$  $1?%1
```